# API's version of a resource URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, routes

I have those API's routes:

```
Fuu::Application.routes.draw do
  scope(:module => 'api', :defaults => {:format => 'json'}) do
    namespace('v1') do
      get 'welcome' => 'welcomes#index'
    end
  end
end
```

As you can see, there's a `v1` module.  But I would like to just have `1` as the version numero, in order to get some URL looking like:

```
https://api.fuu.com/:version/direct_messages/sent.format
```

...where version is just `1`.

I tried to use `namespace('1')`, but it's not possible because a module can not be an integer.

How could we do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change it to a scope then instead of a namespace:

```
Fuu::Application.routes.draw do
  scope(:module => 'api', :defaults => {:format => 'json'}) do
    # API Version 1
    scope('1', :module => 'v1') do
      get 'welcome' => 'welcomes#index'
    end
  end
end
```

Personally, I like your first approach of namespacing the route/module within `v1` since it keeps things organized better.

Comment: Thanks @iWasRobbed.  I think I'm gonna use `scope('1', :module => 'v1')`... keeping the module as you said. Yay

Comment: Glad to hear it!  If my answer helped, please hit the checkmark next to it to close out the question

Comment: Wops just forget this; sorry ;)